# Content not positioned as it should

Tags: html, css

Why is the icon being not positioned under the email address and phone number fields? I know I could probably solve this by placing them in a div but there must be a simple reason for this. Could you explain what is happening and show me how to fix it. Thanks

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}

#foot-address {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2em 2em;
}

#foot-contact {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
}

#facebook-icon {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7c396dc5cb.js"></script>
</head>
<footer>
  <ul id="foot-address">
    <li>12 The Cross</li>
    <li>Bramhope</li>
    <li>Leeds</li>
    <li>LS16 9AX</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="foot-contact">
    <li>popsiesfishandchips@yahoo.co.uk</li>
    <li>0113 2842178</li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" id="facebook-icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>


  <hr>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dsohk0nz/

Comment: what you mean exactly ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really good at wording stuff. Basically I want the facebook icon to be positioned under the email at the side of the address

Comment: you mean under address or on the right of address?

Comment: To right of the address / under the email

Comment: The icon is not under the address, but to the side. The two uls and the a are styled as inline-block. The key here is inline, i.e. one after another, on the same line; all inline elements have the default width set to auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the fiddle below. Please check and tell me if its not exactly what you want.

```
  <ul id="foot-contact">
    <li>popsiesfishandchips@yahoo.co.uk</li>
    <li>0113 2842178</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="facebook-icon"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> </li> 
  </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dsohk0nz/1/

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix (without regard to the rest of the layout), change the last CSS rule to this:

```
#facebook-icon {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a5wL2vz7/1/

Or do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/11bn4m0o/1/

Here I moved the `a` tag with the icon into the `ul` tag that contains the mail address.

Answer (score 0):

In `#facebook-icon` you have used `inline-block`.Replace it with `block`.

Like this:

```
#facebook-icon{
color: #fff;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the link inside a `<li>` in your `<ul id="foot-contact">` and facebook icon will appear bellow your email and phone number.

```
<footer>
   <ul id="foot-address">
        <li>12 The Cross</li>
        <li>Bramhope</li>
        <li>Leeds</li>
        <li>LS16 9AX</li>
   </ul>
   <ul id="foot-contact">
        <li>popsiesfishandchips@yahoo.co.uk</li>
        <li>0113 2842178</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="facebook-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</footer>
```